# Reading a text file then counting the letter freqency and list them from highest to lowest

Tags: java, arrays, io

The software that I have made successfully reads the text file character by character, stores the count of each letter frequency in an Int array, and then lists them out, alphabetically. I need to do a descending format.

What I need help with is how do I store the character count alongside that particular character in an array?

This is an example of the current output I have:

```
    Letter            Frequency
     A                   0 
     B                   1 
     C                   7 
     D                   0  
     E                   14
```

..etc

I need to make it something like this:

```
    Letter            Frequency
     E                   14 
     C                   7 
     B                   1 
     D                   0  
     A                   0
```

This is a snipped from what I have so far:

```
System.out.println("Letter            Frequency");
while ((nextLetter = in.read())!= -1) { 
    current = ((char)nextLetter);  letter
    current = Character.toLowerCase (current);
    if (current >= 'a' && current <= 'z'){ 
      count [current- 'a']++;    
      total++; 
    }
    else{
      other ++;
    }
}
for (int ii=0; ii<26; ii++){
    System.out.printf ("%c                   %d \n", ii+ 'A', count [ii]);
}
```

Comment: Look out for maps (e.g. hashmaps)

Comment: Just change your for loop to for( int ii=25; ii >=0 ;ii--)

Comment: Something else you could do (not super efficient but ok for just 26 chars): look for the largest number in the `count` array and output that together with its index. Then set that count to -1 and repeat until you have written all 26 entries.

Comment: I'm looking into hasmaps as I'm writing this. 
@Henry can you elaborate on your answer? I did not quite understand, especially the last part. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: After you have set the count of the largest entry to -1 if you again search for the maximum value you will find the originally second largest entry and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as  Alfabravo and Henry said we can use `Maps` here and Logic is

> After you have set the count of the largest entry to -1 if you again
>   search for the maximum value you will find the originally second
>   largest entry and so on

Here is the working code: (Tested)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("\\pathtofile\\data.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int nextLetter;
        int[] count = new int[26];
        int total = 0;
        int other = 0;

        System.out.println("Letter            Frequency");    
        while ((nextLetter = br.read()) != -1) {
            char current = (char) nextLetter;
            current = Character.toLowerCase(current);
            if (current >= 'a' && current <= 'z') {
                count[current - 'a']++;
                total++;
            } else {
                other++;
            }
        }
        Map ans = sorting(count);  
        printMap(ans);
    }

    private static Map sorting(int[] count) {
        Map m = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>() {};
        int k = 0 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
             int max =-1;
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
                if(max < count[j]){
                    max = count[j];
                    k = j;
                }
            }     
            count[k] = -1;
            if(max!=0)
            m.put(((char)(k+97))+"", max);
            max=0;
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println("" + entry.getKey() + "     : "+ entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I am just new to the whole idea of Mapping. Thank you so much.

Comment: The LinkedHashMap is not sorted by itself. It keeps a doubly linked list inside to track the insertion order. You are kind of 'misusing' the map as a list because you want to keep character and count together. If you do not actually use the <key, value> mapping for insertion and sorting you should look for a different way.

Comment: Its one method to do the above objective using `<key, value>` Mapping. 
Another method (which @J-S used) is to implement `Comparable` on user defined `Class` with `character` and `count` data members and override `compareTo` method for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a map if you want a sorted list. Create an appropriate class and use Collections.sort().

```
class CharCount implements java.lang.Comparable<CharCount>{
    public int character;
    public int count;
    public CharCount(int a, int b){ character = a; count = b; }
    public String toString(){ return  "" + (char)character + ":" + count; }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CharCount another) {
        return Integer.compare(count, another.count);
    }
};

List<CharCount> hist = new ArrayList<>();
String input = "Halleluja";
for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
    hist.add(new CharCount(i, 0));
}
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    int asc = (int)Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i));
    hist.get(asc - 97).count++;
}
Collections.sort(hist);
Collections.reverse(hist);
System.out.println("histogramm " + hist);
```